# 在。。。中 / 在。。。下 / 在。。。上

Tags: sentence-structure

It is probably quite likely that someone has asked this question before, however the search function doesn't throw anything up and it is actually quite difficult to search for!

Simply put, I have noticed the sentence structures 在...中 / 在...下 / 在...上 and am not entirely sure what they mean， though I can limit their possible meanings from context. For example:

**在**中国和印度两个大国的努力**下** must mean something like "due to" or "as a result of" or "in the process of" or "thanks to".

However, I don't know what it is precisely enough to do use it confidently myself. The same goes for 在...中 and 在...上.

If someone fancies giving a bit of an insight, it'd be much appreciated!

Hashamyim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand them, they are used very similar to how you use them in English.

在．．．中 is like "during", "in the middle of", or just "in"

在．．．下 is like "under" ("Under the rule of...", "Under the stress of...", "Under the efforts of China and India...")

在．．．上 is like "on the..." ("On the merits of...", "On the basis of...")

Answer (score 0):

＂对外汉语常用词语对比例释＂在。。。上  在。。。中  在。。。下 （介词词组）（一）介词＂在＂与＂。。。上＂、＂，，，中＂、＂。。。下＂等方位词组构成介词词组，表示某空间、范围、方面、条件等，但是由于后面的方位词不同，所以意义和用法也不相同。１。＂在。。。上＂：主要表示方面、空间方位、条件等。例如：他在搜集邮票上，下了不少工夫。科学技术是一种在历史上起推动作用的革命力量。在大量实验的基础上，他又作了理论上的总结。
２。＂在。。。中＂：主要表示环境里、范围里等。例如：青年人要在艰苦中奋斗、在奋斗中创业，在创业中成长。他在研究生物工程工作中取得了可喜的成绩。
３。在。。。下＂：主要表示前提条件。在大家的帮助下，他很快就适应了这里的生活。这些作品是在老作家的指导下创作出来的。
４。要注意的是：＂在。。。上＂，＂在。。。下＂都可以表示＂条件＂，但是它们使用的环境不同。＂在。。。上＂所表示的条件不是前提条件，它有一定的工作基础，然后进一步向高发展。例如：我们要在发展生产的基础上，不断改善人民的生活水平。（前-低；后-高）＊我们要在发展生产的基础下，不断改善人民的生活水平。
５。＂在。。。下＂所表示的条件是前提条件，无论肯定的或否定的，都是一种条件。在表示肯定意义的条件中，由于有了这一条件才会出现某种情况，所以形成这一条件的因素通常是高的。例如：在李老师的启发下，大家终于弄明白了这道难题。（前-高；后-低）在社会主义制度下，实行的是按劳分配的分配原则。（前-高；后-低）。＊在李老师的启发上，大家终于弄明白了这道难题。
（二）由＂在＂构成介词词组表示某空间、范围、方面、条件等时，后面一定要有＂上＂、＂中＂、＂下＂等响应的方位词配合，没有是错的。例如：这件事一定在思想上引起注意。在众多的朋友中，我们俩最要好。他在没有任何先进设备的条件下，自己克服困难取得实验的成功。＊这件事一定在思想引起注意。＊在众多的朋友，我们俩最要好。＊他在没有任何先进设备的条件，自己克服困难取得实验的成功。

For more examples users suggest submitting ＂在。。。中、在。。。上、在。。。下＂ to iciba，or also google same.